# Maven : Resolve chain of Dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-2

I have a project Test. Flow of execution is as follows :

- Test needs jar of project X
- project X has a list of other dependent jars ( in its dependency tree). Say order is A -> B -> C -> D -> X

All the projects : A, B, C, D and X are present in the same local directory.

If I create `<modules>` tag in pom of my Test Project, specifying the order of build of jars, like below

```
<modules>
<module>A</module>
<module>B</module>
<module>C</module>
<module>D</module>
<module>X</module>
</modules>
```

it works!

Question : For above thing to work, i Have explicitly mentioned the order of dependencies. I want to avoid this step for situations where the chain of dependencies is huge.

Is it possible that i only write  :

```
<modules>
<module>X</module>
</modules>
```

And some way which can get all the dependent jars and install into my m2 repository

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: First `<modules>` is intended to define the modules which exist. The order should always being defined by the dependencies between the modules. This means if your `X` needs `D` so you should express this by defining a dependency to `D` furthermore `D` should define a dependency to `C` etc. Apart from that you are trying to create integration tests which should always be in a separate module and should be named accordingly (*IT.java`) also using maven-failsafe-plugin..

Comment: @khmarbaise I am learning maven. Can you please elaborate.

I have 4 separate maven projects residing in my local directory : A, B, C and D
and dependency order is A -> B -> C -> D

Now I want to create a project Test which uses D's jar. What is the right way to write the pom for Test project so that when I do mvn install , it brings all the dependent jars in one go.